# Oscillating average position for particle in infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

In Griffith's QM book, problem 2.5(c) asks to calculate the average position of a particle in an infinite well in the initial state $$\psi(x,0) = A(\psi_1 + \psi_2),$$ where $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are the first two eigenstates of the infinite well problem. If we calculate the average position, we find that it oscillates. He makes a sly comment that the amplitude of that oscillation can't be greater than $a/2,$ where $a$ is the width of the box. I don't see why this is. My guess is that this is this state is a mixture of two waves of different momenta, $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, which increases the uncertainty in momentum and further localizes the particle, such that the maximum oscillation for the average would be that of the pure state, which precisely equals $a/2.$ But the problem is that $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are not states of definite momentum, so I'm not sure this argument works. Why is the maximum amplitude equal precisely to the average position of an eigenstate?

Comment: *The amplitude can't be greater than $a/2$. I don't see why this is.* Don’t the wavefunctions vanish for $x<-a/2$ and $x>a/2$?

Comment: “Amplitude” is ambiguous. Often it means the probability amplitude (i.e., the value of the wavefunction). Are you using it to mean the amplitude of oscillation of the expectation value $\langle x\rangle$ as a function of $t$?

Comment: I edited the question to clear things up. @Ghoster yes the wave function vanishes at those points but the position of the box is irrelevant. If the particle is free to move in a box of width $a,$ why isn't the amplitude of this oscillation equal to $a$?

Comment: The amplitude is the maximum distance from the midpoint of the oscillations, not the difference between the maximum and minimum.

Comment: @Buzz is it just a coincidence that it's maximum for pure states and decreases for mixed states?

Comment: @EM_1 Sorry, I don't understand what you are talking about.  For a pure state, the oscillation amplitude can be anything.  If you mean an energy eigenstate, then the oscillation amplitude is zero, as the probability density is time indepdnent.

Comment: @Buzz you're right, I'm sorry. I got confused because the numbers are similar. I forgot that expectation values are time independent for eigenstates.